# Is $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb R)$ an abelian variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, algebraic-groups

I just want to make sure that I have the correct definitions for things. I claim that $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)$ is an abelian variety, which according to Wikipedia is a projective algebraic variety which is also a group, where the group law is a regular map. First, is it correct that $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R) = (\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}) / \sim$, where $(a_1, a_2) \sim (b_1, b_2)$ if there exists some $c \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ such that $(a_1, a_2) = c(b_1, b_2)$?

Anyway, $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)$ is obviously a projective variety, given by $V(0) \subseteq \mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)$, so the first condition holds.

To find a regular map to be the group law on $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)$, I considered the group law to be composition, where I interpret each point $[x : y]$ to be a rotation that brings $[1 : 0]$ to $[x : y]$. Thus I get the group law
$$[x_1 : y_1] + [x_2 : y_2] = [x_1 x_2 - y_1 y_2 : x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1].$$
This law is commutative and associative, has an identity $[1 : 0]$, and has inverses, since $[x : y] + [x : -y] = [1 : 0]$. I *believe* it is also a regular map, since the components of $[x_1 : y_1] + [x_2 : y_2]$ are given by polynomial functions of $x_1, y_2, x_2, y_2$. Thus this law makes $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)$ an abelian group, so it is an abelian variety.

Is all of this right? Please tell me if I'm missing anything or misunderstand any of the definitions.

Comment: I apologize--I don't have time to check all the details. I just wanted to mention that $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{R}$ cannot be an algebraic group. All group curves have genus $1$ by various arguments (e.g. its cotangent bundle must be trivial).

Comment: The term "algebraic variety" is not related to a group structure. The term "algebraic" in this context just means essentially that the coordinate algebras that locally define it are finitely presented and reduced.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft sorry, I think I accidentally replaced "abelian" -> "algebraic" in some places. I'll edit the question, and then it should make more sense :)

Comment: $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)$ is topologically homeomorphic to $S^1$, so yes there is a group law on it which you described. However as @AlexYoucis pointed out the one-dimensional abelian varieties have genus 1 and $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)$ has genus 0. The problem lies in the regularity. A morphism of algebraic varieties is regular if it is given affine locally by polynomials. Without checking it myself I can guarantee you that if you try to check your map affine locally you will find that it's not regular.

Comment: A variety is something defined over a field $k$, but not just the $k$-rational points. For instance, take any variety $X$ over a field $k$ with exactly one $k$-rational point. Then $X(k)$ is the trivial group, but of course $X$ is not an abelian variety.

Answer (score 1):

In the now antiquated language of "classical varieties", everything you wrote would be correct, except that using this language requires that your maps make sense when they take values over a fixed algebraically closed base field. In this case, note that $(i,1) + (i,-1) = (0,0)$, and $(0,0)$ is in neither $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{R})$ nor $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$.

What you've defined is a topological group structure on $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{R})$, where the group operations are "polynomial functions", but the definition of an abelian variety requires more.